# MSVC Compiler Template Sizeof...() not working

Tags: c++, templates, visual-c++

The msvc v19X does not like using the sizeof...() operator in template code.

```
#include<cstddef>

template <typename ValueType, size_t...Indices>
void experiment (ValueType (&theArray)[sizeof...(Indices)])
{
   //code removed
}
```

The above code works fine in Linux, but I need it working in Windows as well.

The failure is with the "sizeof...(Indices)" code. If for example you remove the sizeof...(Indices) and replace it with a number such as 4, it compiles just fine.

I have verified this in Visual Studio and with Compiler Explorer (https://godbolt.org/).

Using Compiler Explorer, I have tried the Clang compiler and it passes as well.

No version of the X64 or X86 msvc v.19x works.

Does anyone have any suggestions. Thank you in advance.
Damon

Comment: *The failure is with the "sizeof...(Indices)" code.* -- this is bad error description. Always post verbatim error messages.

Comment: Please post a MRE (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), including how you use, instantiate or call the code (if we're guessing and we do it right or differently, not resulting in errors or the same errors and you do it differently, we won't have the same result, will we?), show complete error messages and fix the tags!

Comment: Just change it to `template <typename ValueType, size_t N> void experiment (ValueType (&theArray)[N]);`. This is the correct way to do what you're trying.

Comment: Looks like a MSVC bug to me, please report.